# Why is "_" used in active pattern?

Tags: f#

From this [link](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/) I see that they use an "_" in active pattern.

```
 let (|Int|_|) str =
     match System.Int32.TryParse(str) with
     | (true,int) -> Some(int)
     | _ -> None
```

When I look at an example from a different [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) I don't see the underscore.

```
 let (|Even|Odd|) input = if input % 2 = 0 then Even else Odd
```

What is the difference between these two implementations?

Comment: One pattern is complete and the other is partial. The names of both, examples for both, and full descriptions of both are on the page _you_ linked. What is your question exactly..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is written on [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns).
`(|Int|_|) str =...` is partial Active Patterns. `let (|Even|Odd|) input =...` is Active Patterns. See below.

```
// From doc link
module ActivePatternSample =
  let (|Even|Odd|) input = if input % 2 = 0 then Even else Odd 

  let TestNumber input =
    match input with
    | Even -> printfn "%d is even" input
    | Odd -> printfn "%d is odd" input

// Rewrite to partial Active Pattern
module PartialActivePatternSample =
  let (|Even|_|) input =
    match (input%2) with
    | 0 -> Some input
    | _ -> None

  let (|Odd|_|) input =
    match input%2 with
    | 1 -> Some input
    | _ -> None

  let TestNumber input =
    match input with
    | Even input -> printfn "%A is even" input
    | Odd input -> printfn "%A is odd" input
    | _ -> printfn "can not come here"
```

Comment: Thank you for your editing.  I will try to be careful to edit in English. There are few questions of F# in Japan. So I came here.

Comment: Thanks for understanding. Good luck on Stack Overflow! =D